# Why is only header and first row returned when reading data from excel using Java and POI?

Tags: java, excel, cucumber, apache-poi

I am trying to read data from excel file. There are 2 scenarios One is to read all rows of data in the excel sheet (getAllRows) and the second scenario is to (getASingleRow) when the row index is specified. I am currently getting  data back but the only the headers and the first row is getting returned from the method(getAllRows()) while the getASingleRow() returns only the headers. I would appreciate it if someone can help me look at my code. I know that I am doing something wrong. Below are the code samples.

1. Scenario Step Code for Cucumber

```
When user enters data from the supplied excel file at the location
        |Excel        |     Location                               |  Sheet   |
        | ftbank.xlsx |    src/test/resources/testdata/ftbank.xlsx |  data    |
```

2. IDataReader Interface

```
public interface IDataReader {
    /**
     * To get all the rows from the excel
     * @return
     */
    public List<Map<String, String>> getAllRows();

    /**
     * To get a single row from the excel
     * @return
     */
    public Map<String , String> getASingleRow();
}
```

3. Excel Configuration

```
package testing.tables.dataTables;

import java.util.Objects;

public class ExcelConfiguration {
    private final String fileName;

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public String getFileLocation() {
        return fileLocation;
    }

    public String getSheetName() {
        return sheetName;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    private final String fileLocation;
    private final String sheetName;
    private int index = -1;

    private ExcelConfiguration(String fileName, String fileLocation, String sheetName, int index) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.fileLocation = fileLocation;
        this.sheetName = sheetName;
        this.index = index;
    }

    public static class ExcelConfigurationBuilder {
        private String fileName;
        private String fileLocation;
        private String sheetName;
        private int index = -1;

        public ExcelConfigurationBuilder setFileName(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
            return this;
        }

        public ExcelConfigurationBuilder setFileLocation(String fileLocation) {
            this.fileLocation = fileLocation;
            return this;
        }

        public ExcelConfigurationBuilder setSheetName(String sheetName) {
            this.sheetName = sheetName;
            return this;
        }

        public ExcelConfigurationBuilder setIndex(int index) {
            this.index = index;
            return this;
        }

        public ExcelConfiguration build(){
            Objects.requireNonNull(fileName);
            Objects.requireNonNull(fileLocation);
            Objects.requireNonNull(sheetName);
            return new ExcelConfiguration(fileName, fileLocation, sheetName, index);
        }


    }
}
```

4. Excel DataReader: This is where the problem is.

```
public class ExcelDataReader implements IDataReader {
    private final ExcelConfiguration config;
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExcelDataReader.class);

    public ExcelDataReader(ExcelConfiguration config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    //1.get the instance of workbook

    @SneakyThrows
    private XSSFWorkbook getWorkBook() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        return new XSSFWorkbook(new File(config.getFileLocation()));

    }

    //2. get the sheet using the work book object
    private XSSFSheet getSheet(XSSFWorkbook workBook) {
        return workBook.getSheet(config.getSheetName());
    }

    //3. get the header from excel file
    private List<String> getHeaders(XSSFSheet sheet) {
        List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);
        row.forEach((cell) -> {
            headers.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
        });
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(headers);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Map<String, String>> getAllRows() {
        //List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        List<Map<String, String>> data;
        try (XSSFWorkbook workBook = getWorkBook()) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = getSheet(workBook);
            data = getData(sheet);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // to handle exception
            logger.error(e, () -> {
                return String.format("Not able to read the excel %s from location %s", config.getFileName(), config.getFileLocation());
            });
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(data);
        //return data;
    }

    private List<Map<String, String>> getData(XSSFSheet sheet) {
        List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        List<String> headers = getHeaders(sheet);

        for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            Map<String, String> rowMap = new HashedMap<String, String>();
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
            //int headerIndex = 0;
            forEachWithCounter(row, (index, cell) -> {
                rowMap.put(headers.get(index), cell.getStringCellValue());
            });
            data.add(rowMap);
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(data);
    }

    //overloaded getData method
    private Map<String, String> getData(XSSFSheet sheet, int rowIndex) {
        List<String> headers = getHeaders(sheet);
        //Map<String, String> data = new HashedMap<String, String>();
        Map<String, String> rowMap = new HashedMap<String, String>();


        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        //int headerIndex = 0;
        forEachWithCounter(row, (index, cell) -> {
            rowMap.put(headers.get(index), cell.getStringCellValue());
        });

        forEachWithCounter(row, (i, j) -> {

        });

        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(rowMap);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getASingleRow() {
        Map<String, String> data = new HashedMap<String, String>();
        try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = getWorkBook()) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = getSheet(workbook);
            data = getData(sheet, config.getIndex());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // to handle exception
            logger.error(e, () -> {
                return String.format("Not able to read the excel %s from location %s", config.getFileName(), config.getFileLocation());
            });
            return Collections.emptyMap();
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(data);

    }

    private void forEachWithCounter(Iterable<Cell> source, BiConsumer<Integer, Cell> biConsumer) {
        int i = 0;
        for (Cell cell : source) {
            biConsumer.accept(i, cell);
            i++;
        }

    }
}
```

The 2 overloaded methods `getData` is where the problem might likely be as well as the `getAllRows()` and `getASingleRow()`

When the test execution is done with the step definitions

```
public class ExcelReaderStepDefinitions {
    //1. create a method
    //2. parameter to the method would be a map object
    //3. IDataReader would be return type
    //4. @DataTableType

    @When("user enters data from the supplied excel file at the location")
    public void user_enters_data_from_the_supplied_excel_file_at_the_location(IDataReader dataTable) {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        // For automatic transformation, change DataTable to one of
        // E, List<E>, List<List<E>>, List<Map<K,V>>, Map<K,V> or
        // Map<K, List<V>>. E,K,V must be a String, Integer, Float,
        // Double, Byte, Short, Long, BigInteger or BigDecimal.
        //
        // For other transformations you can register a DataTableType.
        System.out.println(dataTable.getAllRows());
        System.out.println("=====SINGLE====");
        System.out.println(dataTable.getASingleRow());
        System.out.println("=========");

        List<Map<String, String>> data = dataTable.getAllRows();
        System.out.println("=========");
        //System.out.println(data.get(1).get("months"));
        System.out.println("=========");

    }


    @DataTableType
    public IDataReader exceltoDataTable(Map<String, String> entry) {
        //sample of map: Excel(header)= <fileName>(value), Location=<fileLocation>
        ExcelConfiguration config = new ExcelConfiguration.ExcelConfigurationBuilder()
                .setFileName(entry.get("Excel"))
                .setFileLocation(entry.get("Location"))
                .setSheetName(entry.get("Sheet"))
                .setIndex(Integer.valueOf(entry.getOrDefault("Index", "0")))
                .build();

        return new ExcelDataReader(config);
    }
}
```

here are the outputs

```
[{Index=abc, months=girl, deposit=mom, ltv=sis, propertyValue=dad, years=boy, loan=bro}]
=====SINGLE====
{Index=Index, months=months, deposit=deposit, ltv=ltv, propertyValue=propertyValue, years=years, loan=loan}
=========
=========
=========
```

The output corresponds to the content of the StepDefinition code.
I want all the rows in the excel sheet to be printed for the method getAllRows() and a single for getASingleRow().
Below is the sample of test data.
[image: test data]

Comment: What is `HashedMap`?

Comment: I've just tried your code. But a bit simplified. But the core logic of your reader works as expected for me. What if you change `Integer.valueOf(entry.getOrDefault("Index", "0"))` to just `0` ?

Comment: are you reading all the data in the excel file and if yes can you help with your simplified version. because I don't know why this is not working

Comment: I've just taken your code and removed cucumber part from it. I ran it in main method. Can you share the file you are reproducing your issue on?

Comment: which file are you referring to here. The issue here is that only the first row is being read. I don't why the forEachWithCounter does not seem to work

Comment: I mean excel file

Comment: I have sample of that on the question if you scroll to the last part of the question. I am unable to attach the file. the file name is ftbank.xlsx and the sheetName is data. if you can see that  one of the rows am reading out from the test is this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252744/discussion-between-jimi-hunter-and-alexey-r).